# UWP Master Detail reference parent context from DataTemplate

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml, master-detail

I'm having trouble getting implementing a Remove button in a UWP Master/Details scenario as per the following sketch.

[image: master/details screen layout]

I'm using the following XAML to generate the screen, which consists of a `ListView` and a `ContentPresenter`, both using `DataTemplate`s to bind to my view models.

```
<Page.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MasterListViewItemTemplate" x:DataType="vm:ListItemViewModel">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                  Height="48"
                  Symbol="Contact" />
      <TextBlock Margin="8,0"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
    </StackPanel>
  </DataTemplate>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="DetailContentTemplate" x:DataType="vm:ListItemViewModel">
    <RelativePanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
      <!-- various input controls -->

      <!-- Unable to reference command in parent context here -->
      <Button x:Name="MasterRemoveButton" Padding="12,0" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}">Remove</button>

    </RelativePanel>
  </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>
...
<Grid x:Name="RoleMasterDetailGrid">
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="MasterColumn" Width="Auto" />
    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="DetailColumn" Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

  <ListView x:Name="MasterListView"
            Grid.Column="0"
            IsItemClickEnabled="True"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource MasterListViewItemTemplate}"
            ItemsSource="{Binding ListItemViewModels}">
    <ListView.Header>
      <Button x:Name="MasterAddNewButton" Padding="12,0" Command="{Binding AddNewCommand}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <SymbolIcon Width="48"
                      Height="48"
                      Symbol="AddFriend" />
          <TextBlock Margin="8,0"
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"
                     Text="Add" Style="{ThemeResource BaseTextBlockStyle}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </Button>
    </ListView.Header>
  </ListView>

  <ContentPresenter
      x:Name="DetailContentPresenter"
      Grid.Column="1"
      BorderThickness="1,0,0,0"
      Padding="20,16"
      BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseLowBrush}"
      Content="{x:Bind MasterListView.SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
      ContentTemplate="{StaticResource DetailContentTemplate}" />

</Grid>
```

However, the `RemoveCommand` command exists on the page view model, not the `ListItemViewModel` and I can't seem to find a way to reference this from the `DataTemplate` of the `ContentPresenter`.

Please could someone advise how to reference the parent context from within a `DataTemplate`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So this can be achieved by directly referencing an element of which you know the `data context`. It uses `Binding ElementName` and works quite well, as long as you have your own decent `naming` and don't have heavy reuse of `templates` across components.

Just the replace the `button` declaration from your code

```
<Button x:Name="MasterRemoveButton" Padding="12,0" Command="{Binding RemoveCommand}">Remove</button>
```

with the below code

```
<Button x:Name="MasterRemoveButton" Content="Remove" Padding="12,0" Command="{Binding ElementName=DetailContentPresenter Path=DataContext.RemoveCommand}"/>
```

Comment: I had no idea it was this trivial! Thanks