# ReactiveUI bind to DataTemplate

Tags: reactiveui

I have an UWP application with ReactiveUI. I have the following in my DataTemplate:

```
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Edit" 
                                    Text="{Binding Resources[EditLabel]}">
```

Since it is a template, I can't access them in my code behind. So how can I setup the binding here?
I tried the Command but then I can only bind to the item itself and not to the ViewModel of the containing view.

EDIT: I adjusted it that way:

```
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Icon="Edit" 
                                    Text="{Binding Resources[EditLabel]}"
                                    Command="{Binding DataContext.EditAccountCommand, ElementName=AccountList}"
```

The Binding does work. I wanted now to add a Converter so I can get the clicked object from the eventargs. But when I add a converter it is executed when the page appears and not when the click is executed. Also I do get the bound command instead of the click arguments.

Comment: If you’re trying to bind to a command in the containing view can you specify the ElementName and Path like in this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48670822

Comment: The binding worked. What I don't get right so far is the converter. I updated my original post.